# Revalidation works only in the local mode

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, next.js, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

So, I have data which needs to be revalidated from a Firebase Realtime database. Everything works fine when I go for `yarn run build` and then `yarn run start`. But when I deploy the website to Vercel, the data does not get revalidated. How can I fix it?

Here is the function:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { postname } }) {
  const fileName = readFileSync(`posts/${postname}.md`, 'utf-8')
  const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileName)
  const snapshot = await retrieveComments(postname).then(snapshot => {
    return { props: { snapshot } }
  })
  const slug = postname

  return {
    props: {
      frontmatter,
      content,
      snapshot,
      slug
    },
    revalidate: 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the combination of `getStaticPaths()`

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: 'blocking' } will server-render pages
  // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
  return { paths:[], fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

and after that use

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { postname } }) {
  const fileName = readFileSync(`posts/${postname}.md`, 'utf-8')
  const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileName)
  const snapshot = await retrieveComments(postname).then(snapshot => {
    return { props: { snapshot } }
  })
  const slug = postname

  return {
    props: {
      frontmatter,
      content,
      snapshot,
      slug
    },
    revalidate: 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! This one seems to be really witty. But there is just one error appearing: `Can't resolve 'fs'`

Comment: Here is the import: `import { readdirSync, readFileSync } from 'fs'`